# How to print a text file using curl to jira api

Tags: linux, bash, shell, curl, jira-rest-api

I am using curl command on linux server to create a jira ticket with certain subject and description using JIRA API.
Now I want to print the Description of jira with the content of a file say test.txt, but I am unable to achieve this. It is always printing the actual command which I use to print the file i.e cat test.txt, below is the command

```
curl -k -D- -u username:password -X POST --data '{"fields":{"project":{"key": "BD"},"summary": "CRITICAL - '"This is the subject part"'","description": "'$(cat text.txt)'","issuetype": {"name": "Support - Other"}}}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -s "https://jiradc.kohls.com:8443/rest/api/2/issue"
```

Please let me know the workable solution

Answer (score 1):

To create an issue using the Jira REST API using `file`, follow these steps:

1.) Create the data file that contains the POST data. For this example, we’ll assume the file is named data.txt.

2.) Add the following JSON to the file:

```
{
    "fields": {
       "project":
       {
          "id": "10000"
       },
       "summary": "No REST for the Wicked.",
       "description": "Creating of an issue using ids for projects and issue types using the REST API",
       "issuetype": {
          "id": "3"
       }
   }
}
```

In this data, the project ID is 10000 and the issue type in our case is 3, which represents a task.  You should pick an ID of a project in your instance and whichever issue type you prefer.

Note that instead of the id you can also use the key and name for the project and issuetype respectively. For example,"key": "TEST" for the project and "name": "Task" for the issuetype.

3.) In Terminal window, run the following command:

```
 curl -u admin:admin -X POST --data @data.txt -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:8080/jira/rest/api/2/issue/
```

As before, adjust details for your environment, such as the hostname or port of the Jira instance. Note that a cloud instance or most public instances would require the use of HTTPS and, of course, valid credentials for the instance.

4.) When your issue is created, check the response that will look something like this:

```
{
   "id":"10009",
   "key":"TEST-10",
    "self":"http://localhost:8080/jira/rest/api/2/issue/10009"
}
```

[JIRA REST API Examples](https://developer.atlassian.com/server/jira/platform/jira-rest-api-examples/)

Comment: I would like to clarify that with the curl command in the question I am able to create the jira issue with proper summary and description. But here the issue is that I am unable to read a text file in curl which has some random generated data in it and I need to print it in the description of the issue. Say, I have a file test.txt with some data in it and I want that data in test.txt to be printed in the description of the jira raised through curl.

Comment: In the data.txt file for the description part is it possible something like: "description": "$(cat test.txt)"

Comment: No it's not possible, but you can update the description which is stored into text file using JIRA rest API

Comment: The data stored in the text file is dynamic. This text file is created by a script and it keeps on changing, which is why I need the curl to take this text file as an input and print the description in the jira issue via jira API